# How can i create a shortcut to close the Download bar in Google Chrome (Windows)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I've done a bit of searching and from what i see there is no such shortcut. There is however [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-clear-downloads/cpbmgiffkljiglnpdbljhlenaikojapc) extension for Google Chrome that does this, it automatically closes the download bar after 5 seconds. However i generally avoid installing extensions. Is there any way to make such a shortcut? Something that seems so small and irrelevant can really make a difference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a chrome extension called **[Always Clear Downloads](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-clear-downloads/cpbmgiffkljiglnpdbljhlenaikojapc).**

> User Reviews:
>
> •First extension that clears the download bar and hides it afterwards.
>
> •I have been looking for an extension that does this! Thank you. Works very well hiding the download bar after the download has completed. Saves a click.